# Will increasing "Bull's Eye" on Hunter increase critical chance for his "Volley"?

Tags: knights-of-pen-and-paper

First of can ***Volley*** even do critical? If it can, will increasing critical chance with ***Bull's Eye*** also increase critical chance for ***Volley***?